# Ubuntu 14.04 Disk Space Full

Tags: disk-management

Ubuntu 14.04 has been installed on 500 Gb HDD. Its saying 0 space. After deleting some huge files, it still doesn't show free space.

Note:

- GUI is not coming up after login
- The files was deleted using bitvise client.

Comment: Is it a fresh installation? Is your system on for a long time?

Comment: Can you get to a command line string, e.g. with Ctrl + Alt + F1 or in recovery mode? If so, what is the output of `df`? Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can restart `lightdm` to try login again:

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` which opens a TTY. There enter your username and password
2. Type `service lightdm restart` try login again
3. If your login was successful show us output of `df -h`

thanks